# Changing the look and feel of java gui components into the windows look and feel

Tags: java, user-interface, look-and-feel

It it possible to change the look and feel on Java GUI into the look and feel of your operating system such as windows? if so, then how do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

To set the look and feel to the current system look and feel:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Answer (score 1):

See [UIManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html).

> UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());